# Qual a propriedade de um componente do COM+ "Nome do Servidor Remoto"

Tags: c#

Estou tendo um problema em achar o nome da propriedade do COM+ para eu possa alterar o conteúdo da mesma, pelas minhas pesquisas eu preciso saber o nome correto do valor do parâmetro para eu conseguir alterar o mesmo, no caso é o **Nome do Servidor Remoto**

```
            COMAdminCatalogCollection applications;
            COMAdminCatalog catalog;

            catalog = new COMAdminCatalog();
            applications = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)catalog.GetCollection("Applications");

            applications.Populate();

            string x = "Nome Sistema";
            dynamic servidor = "Caminho Servidor";

            foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject application in applications)
            {
                if (application.Name == x)
                {
                    application.Value["Nome do parametro que estou atras"] = servidor;
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação da Microsoft
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686107(v=vs.85).aspx#applicationproxyservername

O que você precisa é do **ApplicationProxyServerName**

```
COMAdminCatalogCollection applications;
COMAdminCatalog catalog;

catalog = new COMAdminCatalog();
applications = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)catalog.GetCollection("Applications");

applications.Populate();

string x = "COM+ Explorer";
dynamic servidor = "localhost";

foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject application in applications)
{
    if (application.Name == x)
    {
        application.Value["ApplicationProxyServerName"] = servidor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Funcionou aqui...